# Absolute value inequality with variable on both sides

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to solve the following inequality:

> $$|3-5x| \le x$$

I am not familiar with inequalities including one absolute value with variables on both sides. I tried to solve it as follows:

> $$-x \le 3-5x \le x$$

Then I solved for each side separately,as follows:

> $$3-5x \le x$$
>
> $$  x \ge (1/2)$$

---

> $$-x \le 3-5x$$
>
> $$x \le \frac34$$

I know my solution is incorrect and that it actually lies between $\frac12$ and $\frac34$, but I wanted to know what is wrong with my method and what is the appropriate approach to solving such inequalities.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I learned it back in Algebra I.

You can split it into two equations. Since the sign is $\le$, it will be that Equation 1 *and* Equation 2 are true.

Here are the steps:

$$|3-5x| \le x$$

---

$$3-5x \le x  \;\;\;\;\;| \;\;-3+5x\le x $$

---

$$6x \ge 3  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;| \;\;-4x \ge -3$$

---

$$x \ge \frac 12  \;\;\;| \;\;\;\;x \le \frac 34$$

---

$$\frac 12 \le x \le \frac 34$$

Comment: This should be sufficient, but for further elaboration just reply

Comment: This approach is very specific towards linear inequalities (but definitely works, I think)--it doesn't work (I believe) for higher order ones.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was trying to give a simple easy-to-understand solution.

Comment: Your "$|$" symbol is for AND or OR?  In either case you have a logical issue as you start of with an OR and end with and AND.

Comment: @Maccavity And. And please point out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Divide $ -x \leq 3-5x \leq x $ by $x$ and go from there. Although I think what you have is correct, the solution IS the interval $ \dfrac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \dfrac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break up the absolute value into its intervals:

$$
|x| = \begin{cases}
x & x > 0 \\
-x & x < 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore for $|3-5x|$ you need to find the interval when it's less than zero and when it's greater than zero:

$$
|3-5x| = \begin{cases}
3 - 5x & 3 - 5x > 0 \rightarrow 3 > 5x \rightarrow x < \frac{3}{5}\\
5x - 3 & 3 - 5x < 0 \rightarrow 3 <5x \rightarrow x > \frac{3}{5} \\
0 & 3 - 5x = 0 \rightarrow 3 = 5x \rightarrow x = \frac{3}{5}
\end{cases}
$$

Now you solve the inequality in each case:

1. $x < \frac{3}{5} \rightarrow |3 - 5x| = 3 - 5x$
   $$
   3 - 5x \leq x \\
   3 \leq 6x \\
   x \geq \frac{1}{2}
   $$
2. $x > \frac{3}{5} \rightarrow |3 - 5x| = 5x - 3$
   $$
   5x - 3 \leq x \\
   4x \leq 3 \\
   x \leq \frac{3}{4}
   $$
3. $x = \frac{3}{5} \rightarrow |3 - 5x| = 0$
   $$
   0 \leq x \\
   x \geq 0
   $$

*Now* you need to analyze each case:

1. $x < \frac{3}{5} \wedge x \geq \frac{1}{2}$

It is true that $\frac{3}{5} = \frac{6}{10} \geq \frac{5}{10}$.  Therefore this particular interval is true for $\frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{3}{5}$.

2. $x > \frac{3}{5} \wedge x \leq \frac{3}{4}$

Since $\frac{3}{5} = \frac{12}{20}$ and $\frac{3}{4}  = \frac{15}{20}$, this is true for $\frac{3}{5} < x \leq \frac{3}{4}$.

3. $x = \frac{3}{5} \wedge x \geq 0$

$\frac{3}{5} > 0$ therefore this is trivially satisfied--thus $x = \frac{3}{5}$ *is* allowed.

When we combine these results, we find that $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{4}$.

**PS Edit:**

It's probably easier to use:

$$
|x| = \begin{cases}
x & x \geq 0 \\
-x & x \leq 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

In that case you get the two intervals:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{5}
$$

and

$$
\frac{3}{5} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{4}
$$

Which clearly combines to give: $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was correct except you needed to use the word **AND** correctly.
The inequality $-x \le 3-5x \le x$ is equivalent to the inequalities

\begin{align}
   -x \le 3-5x \quad &\text{AND} \quad 3-5x \le x \\
   4x \le 3 \quad &\text{AND} \quad 3 \le 6x \\
   x \le \frac 34 \quad &\text{AND} \quad \frac 12 \le x \\
   \frac 12 \le x \quad &\text{AND} \quad x \le \frac 34 \\
x &\in\left[\frac 12, \frac 34 \right]
\end{align}